# Why no ubuntu -v command?

Tags: command-line

I know that `lsb_release -a` as a terminal command will achieve exactly what I want (that is a quick printout of my installed Ubuntu release - 15.04).

My question is more one of accessibility. Terminal commands that I would imagine are related exclusively to Ubuntu (it's version) are not referenced by a clear and logical `ubuntu -v` that is consistent with command flags for other queries I run through the terminal.

This question is not a feature request but rather that I genuinely believe there must be a good reason for this. I suspect this is due to a fundamental misunderstanding that Ubuntu is not an 'app' or a 'program' but rather a collection of code running in concert... but I'm not sure  and even then having ubuntu utility functions with it's own command would seem to make sense, no?

Are these things matters of historic debate in ubuntu (can someone point me to a launchpad flame war?) or is just point blank abusurd for some very good reason?

Comment: Why would there be such a command? `lsb_release` is the standard way, why would Ubuntu make their own? Remember that Ubuntu is Linux, the basic tools are available there, it would be _awful_ to have to learn different commands for each Linux distribution.

Comment: Right so the core of this then becomes what is the history of the lsb_release method? I feel like what I want to ask is 'what's my version of ubuntu' by comparison lsb_release seems obscure. My question is why that is necessary?

Comment: For the same reason `ls` is not `ubuntuls` and `mv` is not `ubuntumv`. What would be the point? The method you describe is a universal Linux thing, it has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Imagine the madness if each distribution changed the names of standard commands! They would suddenly become incompatible, programs would have to be re-written for each distro, we would need to relearn all commands again and for what? What would be improved?

Comment: I see what your saying but the version of ubuntu is tied to an ubuntu release. Whereas the content of my folder is not. I'm not arguing for a complete rewrite of the entire command set just why ones that naturally pertain to ubuntu don't have a single rallying command?I

Comment: Please come into [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) to discuss this. The comments are not the place for it. Nothing "naturally pertains to ubuntu" and certainly not the command that returns the OS name!

Comment: `man lsb_release`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command to print out the version in the terminal:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

alternatively, you can also use this instead:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

I believe the reason it's not available is because, if anybody wants it that way, they can just run the following command to make it that way:

```
echo 'alias ubuntu-version="cat /etc/lsb-release"' | tee -a ~/bashrc; . ~/.bashrc
```

then, type the following command to see the version:

```
ubuntu-version
```

Also, logically, there can be no:

```
ubuntu -v
```

because there is no command:

```
ubuntu
```